# Java: type parameter must implement interface

Tags: java, syntax, interface

I have a type `T` that implements interface `I`, how do I specify that a method takes an object `T` that implements `I`, eg.

```
public SomeClass(T<implements I> parameter) {
     ....
}
```

Comment: `public <T extends I> void SomeClass(T parameter) {}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public someReturnType someMethod(I parameter) {
     ...
}
```

Comment: How can I access a method of `T` then?

Comment: Well, if you want to access methods of `T`, then the fact that it implements `I` is irrelevant - you can just pass it as `someMethod(T parameter)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply specify the Interface type I as the method parameter. Following method can accept any sub type of interface `I`

```
public void yourMethod(I param) {
     ...
}
```